# iOS 4. UITouch's locationInView doesn't acknowledge retina display. Bug or feature?

Tags: ios4, uitouch, retina-display

Is there a reason that UITouch's locationInView: is unaware of the presence (or not) of a retina display? Why is the rescaling for retina display left as a task for the developer. Seems odd to me.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: I have to scale the locationInView manually, it seems odd to me too.

Answer (score 0):

It's by design. The location is reported as in points, not as in pixels. From Apple's Event Handling Guide:

> iOS 4.0 still reports touches on iPhone 4 (and on future high-resolution devices) in a 320x480 coordinate space to maintain source compatibility, but the resolution is twice as high in each dimension for applications built for iOS 4.0 and later releases.